# How can I output NUL correctly to a file via a script?

Tags: bash, scripting

```
$ FILE="$(mktemp)"
$ printf "a\0\n" > "$FILE"
$ od -tx1z "$FILE"
0000000 61 00 0a                                         >a..<
0000003
```

So far so good.

I wrapped the above into a bash script

```
#! /bin/bash

cmd=("$@")
FILE="$(mktemp)"
eval "${cmd[@]}" > "$FILE"
od -tx1z "$FILE"
```

but

```
$ script printf 'a\0\n' 
0000000 61 30 6e                                         >a0n<
0000003
```

Why does the output change `\0` to literal string? How can I prevent that from happening?

---

Not very important in this post: my question comes from that I am trying to wrap some commands into a bash script, so to [prevent a command expansion from removing NUL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607352/):

```
FILE="$(mktemp)"
printf "a\0\n" > "$FILE"
S="$(uuencode -m "$FILE" /dev/stdout)"
uudecode -o /dev/stdout <(printf "$S") | od -tx1
rm "$FILE"
```

Comment: Please use `printf '%s' "$S"` the other in your question is unsafe to the contents of `$S`.

Comment: can you please tell me why?

Comment: Because `printf` is designed to have format and the string separated. When using `printf` without an explicit format the string could be modified by any of the escapes that also afect the command `echo`. Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) and [entry 2. in here](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the output change `\0` to literal string? How can I prevent that from happening?

Because you used `eval`, which adds another level of shell processing. `eval` runs the command `printf a\0\n`, where the backslashes escape the zero and the `n`, leaving them as-is with the backslash removed.

You could prevent that by well, not using `eval`. Just using `"$@" > "$FILE"`  should work to run the command given as arguments to the script. Though in that case, you couldn't use redirections or other shell syntax there, as you could with `eval`. Or, you could redesign the whole thing so that you don't need to pass commands as arguments.

> I am trying to wrap some commands into a bash script, so to prevent a command expansion from removing NUL:
>
> ```
> S="$(uuencode -m "$FILE" /dev/stdout)"
> ```

Is that a problem here? `uuencode -m` shouldn't produce any NUL bytes. Exactly the opposite, since it encodes binary data to text.

That last script writes an `a`, a NUL, and a newline to `$FILE` and passes the same to `od`, which prints out the hex representation of those, `0000000    61  00  0a`, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain "though in that case, you couldn't use redirections or other shell syntax there, as you could with eval"?  It seems that  the redirection in `"${cmd[@]}" > "$FILE"` works.

Comment: @Ben, if you run `script "echo foo > bar"` or `script echo foo ">" bar`, and the script runs `eval "$@"`, the `>` passed as an argument to the script will be taken as the redirection operator by `eval`, and you'll see the output go to the file `bar`. But if the script runs `"$@"` without `eval` instead, then the first one will give an error, and the second will output the string `foo > bar`. In neither case is the `>` in the argument interpreted as a redirection operator.

Comment: Thanks. I found that when `cmd=( "ls" "|" "cat")` `"${cmd[@]}"` doesn't run by itself, but need `eval "${cmd[@]}"`. `cmd="ls | cat"` also need `eval "$cmd"`. So when do I need `eval` and when do I not need `eval` to run a string or an array of strings as a command?

Comment: When will using `eval` fail to run a command (here is an example), while not using `eval` will succeed?

Answer (score 1):

You could output a NUL to stdout, stderr or receive it from stdin.
Any "internal" **capture** and (almost) any use of a NUL is a problem.

You can emit a NUL to stdout:

```
$ printf 'a\0b' | sed -n l
a\000b$
```

Or:

```
$ printf 'a\0b' | cat -A
a^@b
```

And to a file also:

```
$ printf 'a\0b' >outfile
```

And **exactly** that works in scripts as well.

## eval

The problem with your first script is that it is using `eval`:

```
$ cmd=(printf 'a\0b\n')
$ echo "${cmd[@]}"
printf a\0b\n

$ eval echo "${cmd[@]}"
printf a0bn
```

In the second loop tru the shell line parsing backslashes were removed.
Just don't use eval:

```
$ "${cmd[@]}"| sed -n l
a\000b$
```

## expansions

That goes to prove that both (the builtin) `printf` and `stdout` are able to use NULs.

But this fails:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(printf 'a\0b')" | cat -A
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
ab$
```

There is even (in bash 4.4+) a warning message.

In short, the shell (most shells) use C-strings internally, a C-string ends in the first NUL. Some shells cut at the first NUL in a "command expansion".

```
$ ksh -c 'echo $(printf "a\0b\n")|sed -n l'    # also yash
a$
```

Some remove the NUL

```
$ bash -c 'echo $(printf "a\0b\n")|sed -n l'
ab$
```

And some even change the NUL to an space:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $(printf "a\0b\n")|sed -n l'
a b$
```

Similar problems happen with assignments to variables.

## encode

Yes, the answer you link to use `uuencode` to encode (and decode) the file content.

A simpler approach seems to be to use `xxd` (which can reverse octal dumps):

```
FILE="$(mktemp)"
printf "a\0b\n" > "$FILE"
S=$(xxd -p "$FILE")
xxd -r -p <(printf '%s' "$S") | xxd -p
rm "$FILE"
```